# How to check if the length of a requested video file is greater than `x` minutes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, https, python-requests

I'm currently writing a script to scrape video files from a website. One thing is that I don't wish to download any videos with a length greater than 20 minutes.

Lets say I've got a URL, `url`. I want to check what the length of this video is before I actually request the entire file. Obviously, requesting a full 20 minute long video will take quite a bit of time, so requesting it and then checking isn't an option. I'm pretty sure it is possible, since all browsers will show the length of a video before the entire video is loaded, so I'd just have to copy whatever they're doing, and put it into my code.

It would look something like this (with SOME_MAGIC_FUNCTION substituted for whatever function I should be looking for):

```
if parse_time(SOME_MAGIC_FUNCTION(url)) < (20*60):
    file_content = requests.get(url).content
else:
    continue
```

I'm using python's `requests` module for this, so preferably give answers that use this module.

Comment: While some servers and frameworks might send response headers with metadata about the video, I highly doubt that is standarized.